# Name all sheets in w orkbook based on the cell value of each sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have used this code before but just changed it to a different cell and am now receiving a Run-Time error '1004' Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet' failed . Not sure what is causing this

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 ws.Name = ws.Range("FW1")
 Next
```

Comment: There are many characters that are not allowed in the sheet name.  make sure non of these are in that cell.  Also blank cells will cause an error.

Comment: all sheets have cell FW 1 populated with alphanumeric text

Comment: As a suggestion try this `ws.Name = WorksheetFunction.Clean(ws.Range("FW1"))`

Comment: We can't possibly tell you why it does not work.  When it stops figure out what on which sheet it stopped.  Go to FW1 on that sheet and parse the cell to see if every character is allowed.

Comment: Still got the error

Comment: Found the problem. I'm an idiot one of the values was in DW not FW and it was erroring cause of the empty cell if FW on that one sheet

Comment: You should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The name of the sheet must be a string and you are assigning a range object to it, so you have to do this instead:

```
 ws.Name = ws.Range("FW1").value
```